# Solving large ODE system in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and I am trying to solve the following system numerically:

[image]

I can solve it for the case of a single S but I need to do it for N=1000 (i runs from 1 to N) and I am not sure how to extend my code.

```
clearvars;
tSpan = [0 10];

S0 = [1/2*sind(45)*cosd(45) 1/2*sind(45)*sind(45)  1/2*cosd(45)];

[t,S] = ode45(@eom,tSpan,S0);

plot(t,S(:,1),t,S(:,2),t,S(:,3))
legend('Sx','Sy','Sz')

%plot(S(:,1),S(:,2));
```

In file eom.m

```
function dSdt = eom(t,S)
    G=5;
    k=1;
    deltax = -G*k*S(1);
    deltay =-G*k*S(2);
    B(1) = 2*k*deltax;
    B(2) = 2*k*deltay;
    B(3) = k*k;

    dSdt = [B(2)*S(3)-B(3)*S(2);B(3)*S(1)-B(1)*S(3);B(1)*S(2)-B(2)*S(1)];
end
```